# Display: none изображению

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть страница, на ней есть картинки, всё хорошо. НО, пытаюсь добавить новые картинки, которым почему-то присваивается style="display: none !important". В любой части страницы. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде разобрался, картинки назывались `adv1.jpg`, `adv2.jpg` и т.д. Переименовал их и всё стало работать. Интересно было бы узнать почему так.

Comment: Возможно, adblock блокирует

Answer (score 2):

adv_2.jpg - та же ситуация, а вот adv_1.jpg, adv_3.jpg, adv_4.jpg... все нормально

Ответ - дело исключительно в имени файла. Я разобрался в чем дело: плагин AdBlock плохо относится к файлам с таким именем, и блокирует его как рекламу

Comment: Вы оба хот сказали, куда это пихаете, в смысле CMS. И надо бы научиться пользоваться веб-инспектором.

Comment: дело исключительно в имени файла. Я разобрался в чем дело:  плагин AdBlock плохо относится к файлам с таким именем, и блокирует его как рекламу

Comment: Во, хорошо. Держи плюсик :)